# Auto assign to team lead/developer on bug reopen

Tags: jira

In my implementation of JIRA, I have a custom field called *Developer* which gets populated automatically (username) whenever someone move the JIRA from Open to Fixed state. Now I want something similar for the Fixed to Reopen transition. That is, whenever the tester changes the status to Reopen, it should go back to the Developer or the Project Lead (in case the field isnt populated as the custom field can be overridden).

I tried to implement a post function, but there isn't a way where I can use OR criteria. Or is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find a workaround for this.

1. Download the [Workflow Enhancer for JIRA plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.tng.jira.plugins.workflowenhancer/) (FREE). You would also need [JIRA Suite Utilities](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities/) (I had it installed already for some other customization)
2. In the Fixed to Reopen transition, add a Post Function and use `Copy Value From Other Field` to update *Assignee* from *Developer* field
3. Then add another Post Function underneath this where you need to use `Universal Post Function`. Here make the boolean condition as *{Assignee}==""* and select *Choose post function to execute:* as *Assign to Lead Developer*
4. Publish the draft.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [Post Function](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Post+Functions+With+Comments) on the transition using the [Script Runner plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) if its a self-hosted JIRA instance which will allow you great flexibility in the logic to fill the target field in.

Comment: I'm not familiar with scripting in JIRA. I have installed the plugin. Now how do I script so that I can implement a logic to ensure the assignee field is set correctly.

Comment: In fact, I tried to use the `Script Post-Function` option, but there isnt an option where I can write custom script to suit my need